# Where is .cvs file for the email translation in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates, order-email, email-translation

I want to change some styles and translation in: the body, the name that appear in "name from" of the inbox and subject of the mails of Magento is sending.
Where are need to make the changes?

I'm using Magento2 and i looked in this path:

> \app\design\frontend\{nameTheme}\{nameTheme}\i18n\

And found a `.cvs` file with some translation, but none of them have the sentences i'm looking for.

- Is it okey if i add the sentence I want to translate in the file that i found in the path?
- Where else i need to check?
- The .cvs file can store the translation of the subject and the name from that you see in your inbox?

If anyone can explain me where Magento 2 took the translation for the mails and the templates to build the email and sent it, it will me awesome!!!

Note: all the sentence of the templates were written like this: `{{trans "View past orders"}}`. So the content of the mails are dynamic.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: for more detail check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Phrase class sometimes has only a Placeholder renderer that returns only keys, not their translations. 
To solve this problem you can try to reload in `\Magento\Framework\App\Area`
the translate part
`$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\AreaInterface::PART_TRANSLATE)`
or set CompositeRenderer to `Phrase`

```
\Magento\Framework\Phrase::setRenderer(
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Phrase\RendererInterface::class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

Just add your language phrase and this will work.

> \app\design\frontend{nameTheme}{nameTheme}\i18n\

Additionally you might need clear the cache:

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: I add the sentence, reset cache and the mails didn't change. =( any other idea?

Comment: I reset the cache from the application, it have the same effect that run that command, right?

Comment: Should be yes, but try clear cache from console, just in case. May be it solve the problem?

Comment: Nop, it not solve the problem =(

Comment: You sure that you changed correct email template? If change layout or remove translate sentence - this changes apllied correct?

Comment: I'm not changing emails templates. I want to translate the sentences because i have incomplete translations. Half of the body of the mail is in English and the other in Spanish. I want to translate all the sentences and don't create new templates all in Spanish.

Comment: Have you set the language for your store view and is the csv file named the same as the language code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check for your questions ?

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Comment: I followed the steps of that link, and the mails didn't change. I create new templates using the base ones and add the sentences in the .cvs file reset cache from the application but the mails didn;t change the language. Any other idea?